# Disable deleting element in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to disable deleting an element from contenteditable. I have the following markup and when user presses backspace or delete key if cursor is next to image element I want the image not to be deleted and cursor to move to prev/next char, Using pure JavaScript HTML CSS and not jQuery.
[image]

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    some text and                      //user can delete this         
    <img id="img" src="someimg.gif"/> //user can't delete this
    more text                         // user can delete this
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make part of contentEditable unable to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014713/make-part-of-contenteditable-unable-to-delete)

Answer (score -1):

Try to split contenteditable into two parts.

something like this:

```html
<div id="content"> 
<p contenteditable="true">
    some text and            
</p>
    <img id="img" src="someimg.gif"/>
<p contenteditable="true">
    more text
</p>
</div>
```

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score -1):

just separate them :)

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
 //user can delete this 
   </p> some text and</p>
</div>
 
<img id="img" src="someimg.gif"/>
 //user can't delete this, also add display 
 //inline-block to this in the CSS so it doesn't go down

<div id="content" contenteditable="true">   
// user can delete this       
   <p> more text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: if I need more image ?